# Cut function split by factor levels

Tags: r

I have a problem with the cut function. I have this situation:

```
 codice
1 11GP2-0016
2 11GP2-0016
3 11GP2-0016
4  11OL2-074
5  11OL2-074
```

and I would like to have a new variable "campione" splitted by variable "codice" like this:

```
    codice campione
1 11GP2-0016    [1,3]
2 11GP2-0016    [1,3]
3 11GP2-0016    [1,3]
4  11OL2-074    (4,5]
5  11OL2-074    (4,5]
```

How can I use the cut function to split the "codice" creating a variable showing that from 1 to 3 i have the same code, from 4 to 5 same code and so on?

I need to solve another question. For the same issue I would like to obtain:

```
 codice campione
1 11GP2-0016    [11GP2-0016,11GP2-0016,11GP2-0016]
2 11GP2-0016    [11GP2-0016,11GP2-0016,11GP2-0016]
3 11GP2-0016    [11GP2-0016,11GP2-0016,11GP2-0016]
4  11OL2-074    (11OL2-074,11OL2-074]
5  11OL2-074    (11OL2-074,11OL2-074]
```

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: Do you just want to know the run length, or is it important to have the start and end position? (see `?rle`)

Comment: is it important the position because 1 to 3 it means sample1 to sample3. Not the length. @hadley example is good but seems that the rank is following something different than the position. Nicola

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it. You can add brackets/parens, if you want.

```
dat <- read.table(text='codice
1 11GP2-0016
2 11GP2-0016
3 11GP2-0016
4  11OL2-074
5  11OL2-074', header=TRUE)

within(dat, 
    campione <- with(rle(as.character(codice)), {
        starts <- which(! duplicated(codice))
        ends <- starts + lengths - 1
        inverse.rle(list(values=paste(starts, ends, sep=','), lengths=lengths))
    })
)

#       codice campione
# 1 11GP2-0016      1,3
# 2 11GP2-0016      1,3
# 3 11GP2-0016      1,3
# 4  11OL2-074      4,5
# 5  11OL2-074      4,5
```

Comment: Best way for me. Using @Gavin Simpson solution the intervals are not correct. No matter for me about brakets ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using your data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "1 11GP2-0016
2 11GP2-0016
3 11GP2-0016
4  11OL2-074
5  11OL2-074", row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(d) <- "codice"
```

Here is a slightly convoluted example using `rle()`:

```
drle <- with(d, rle(codice))
```

This gives us the run lengths of `codice`:

```
> drle
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:2] 3 2
  values : chr [1:2] "11GP2-0016" "11OL2-074"
```

and it is the `$lengths` component that I manipulate to create two indicates, the start (`ind1`) and the end (`ind2`) location:

```
ind1 <- with(drle, rep(seq_along(lengths), times = lengths) +
                     rep(c(0, head(lengths, -1) - 1), times = lengths))
ind2 <- ind1 + with(drle, rep(lengths- 1, times = lengths))
```

Then I just paste these together:

```
d <- transform(d, campione = paste0("[", ind1, ",", ind2, "]"))
```

Giving

```
> head(d)
      codice campione
1 11GP2-0016    [1,3]
2 11GP2-0016    [1,3]
3 11GP2-0016    [1,3]
4  11OL2-074    [4,5]
5  11OL2-074    [4,5]
```

Comment: Nice, although *you*'re missing the rounded left parens on the second level of that factor...  (Just kidding. Your notation's better.)

Comment: Yeah, I know as I failed to even both using `cut()`! Bad me! ;-) Hope the OP doesn't mind - those are nicer but just labels that `cut()` produces... The OP can convert to a factor if the want... (And thanks by the way!)

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, the interval `(4,5]` shouldn't include the 4th element at all, which is why yours is **objectively** better.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use `rank`:

```
left <- rank(factor(d$codice), ties.method = "min")
right <- rank(factor(d$codice), ties.method = "max")
d$campione <- paste("[", left, ",", right, "]", sep = "")
```

Comment: Dear Hadley, I think that I'm doing something wrong because your way is easier for me than otherones but I have a problem because the rank doesen't start from 1 but it starts from 395 (my databse is around 900 cases). Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: what I would like to do is to find duplicated rows in my data frame by some variables. In this case only one "Codice" but further I'd like to use more than one variable.